# How do I partition a new hard drive with no OS? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have an Acer Aspire desktop whose hard drive went bad. I installed a new 1T Seagate Barracuda (which replaced a 750M Barracuda). I made recovery disks when I first got the desktop, but when I put disk 1 in, it gets to the recovery options page and won't let me select an option (one is to format the disk and the other is to format it and retain the user files). All I can select is "Exit," which of course restarts the whole process. Is this because it's not partitioned? If so, how do I partition a disk that doesn't yet have a functioning OS on it? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it's not detecting your hard disk drive.  Can you see the drive during POST or in the BIOS?

Comment: I should add, you don't need to partition it.  The Acer Recovery Management software you're using should take care of that automatically.

Comment: Jason, thanks for your quick reply. I opened up the tower to start some troubleshooting steps to get my hard drive to register and realized I never plugged in either of the cables, so I'm going to delete this post and go open a computer repair shop. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  If you're unable to delete it, I've provided the information in an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As was found out in the comments to the question in discussion between [Jason](https://superuser.com/users/274091/jason) and [McScribble](https://superuser.com/users/354909/mcscribble), the problem was caused by **the hard disk drive not being connected.**

Answer (score 0):

The Acer Recovery Management software will partition the drive automatically.

The fact that it's not giving you a recovery option is an indication that it's not detecting a hard drive being present.